# limit number of selected checkboxes

Tags: dart, flutter

i have multiple checkboxes .. in which you can select more than one checkbox ... like this:

```
for (var a in user.poll.questions[i].options) {
          children.add(
            new Row(
              children: [
                new Checkbox(
                    value: questionList.contains(a.id),
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        //if (questionList.length < user.poll.questions[i].maxChoice){
                        newValue
                            ? questionList.add(a.id)
                            : questionList.remove(a.id);
                        //}
                      });
                      answers[user.poll.questions[i].id] = questionList;
                    }),
                new Text(
                  a.text,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
```

but i want to limit number of checked boxes .. am getting the max choices number from json .. how to limit the selection of checkedboxes by it?

for example if

> int maxChoices = 3;

how can i let the user selects maximum of 3 checkboxes?

Comment: What should happen when the limit is reached and another checkbox is checked?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it shouldn't be checked and a text displayed that you reached the maximum number ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to do something like this?

```
(newValue && questionList.length >= maxChoices)
    ? showAlert() : setState(() {
        newValue
            ? questionList.add(a.id)
            : questionList.remove(a.id);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You should use this package for single selection, limited selection, and multiple selections of checkboxes in Flutter.

> flutter_limited_checkbox: ^0.0.1
> [Click here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_limited_checkbox)

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_limited_checkbox

> Model

```dart
  List<FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel> myCheckBoxList=[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_01', selectId: 1));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_02', selectId: 2));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_03', selectId: 3));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_04', selectId: 4));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_05', selectId: 5));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_06', selectId: 6));
    myCheckBoxList.add(FlutterLimitedCheckBoxModel(selectTitle: 'Option_07', selectId: 7));
    super.initState();
  }
```

> Single CheckBox

```dart
FlutterSingleCheckbox(
        singleValueList: mySingleValueList,
        onChanged: (index){

        },

      )
```

> Limited Checkbox

```dart
FlutterLimitedCheckbox(

        limit: 3,
        limitedValueList: mySingleValueList,
        onChanged: (List<FlutterSelectModel> list){

        },
      )
```

> Unlimited Checkbox

```dart
FlutterUnlimitedCheckbox(

        unlimitedCheckList: mySingleValueList,
        onChanged: (List<FlutterSelectModel> list){

        },
      )
```

Thanks